# How to determine RAM used per index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb, ram

I've created several indices through CouchDB River plugin on Elasticsearch 1.7. I have node stats but can't determine the amount of RAM used per index. I want to use this data to see if I can get rid of indices using large amounts of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, the memory usage of an index is basically two parts: one which is "static" and represents the memory used by the data itself, and another one which depends more or less on the search usage (caches, buffers, dynamic memory structures).

You need to look at the indices stats to see this usage: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-stats.html

And from there, you search for the index you are interested in and you look at these sections: ***filter_cache, id_cache, fielddata, percolate, completion, segments*** (this is the "static" usage I mentioned above), ***query_cache***.